# Cycle each consecutive row of a matrix to the right by 1 position

Tags: r, matrix

I don't even really know how to describe what I want to do, so hopefully the title makes at least some sense.

Better if I show you:

I have a simple 3x5 matrix of letters a to e:

```
matrix(data = rep(letters[1:5], 3), nrow = 3, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
```

It gives this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
[2,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
[3,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"
```

I would like to change it to this without typing it manually:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
[2,] "e"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
[3,] "d"  "e"  "a"  "b"  "c"
```

I'm thinking some kind of loop system or similar, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple case you might try this `for` loop.

```
n <- dim(m3)[2]
for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))[-1]) {
  m3[i, ] <- c(m3[i, (n - i + 2):n], m3[i, 1:(n - i + 1)])
}
m3
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
# [2,] "e"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
# [3,] "d"  "e"  "a"  "b"  "c"
```

To let the pattern repeat for a longer matrix, we might generalize:

```
n <- dim(m7)[2]
for (i in seq_len(nrow(m7))[-1]) {
  j <- i %% 5
  if (j == 0) j <- 5
  if (j > 1) m7[i, ] <- c(m7[i, (n - j + 2):n], m7[i, 1:(n - j + 1)])
}
m7
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
# [2,] "e"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
# [3,] "d"  "e"  "a"  "b"  "c" 
# [4,] "c"  "d"  "e"  "a"  "b" 
# [5,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "a" 
# [6,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
# [7,] "e"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"
```

---

*Data:*

```
m3 <- matrix(data=letters[1:5], nrow=3, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
m7 <- matrix(data=letters[1:5], nrow=7, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks very much.  I actually had an n x n matrix (a square), so the simple solution worked perfectly. It is good to have the extra code should the dimensions be different.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable called ord `ord <- seq_len(ncol(m))`

Within the map function use the `ord` and the `max(ord)` to create some integers that will be used to subset the array.

Then rbinding the result with `do.call(rbind)`

Where `m` is the matrix

```
library(purrr)

do.call(rbind, map2(ord, nrow(m),   \(x,y) 
                    m[y, c(x:max(ord),
                           ord[- (x:max(ord))])]
                    )[c(1,rev(ord))]
        )
```

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
[2,] "e"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
[3,] "d"  "e"  "a"  "b"  "c" 
[4,] "c"  "d"  "e"  "a"  "b" 
[5,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "a" 
[6,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"
```